# Debugging popup extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I open:
**Incpect Popup**
Next select tab **scripts**
I get samtimes empty list scriprs.

I write a simply extension manifest.json (my minimum)

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
        "popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST1</h1>
<div id="content">
TEST
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
console.log('test OK');
```

Sometimes I get list but not with all my js files.
This file is only short example. I send to console message, and I see this message and I see this file in resource, but i not see in the **scripts** tab.

My chrome version is 9.0.597.98.
I try with other version and I have the same problem.
[image: Empty]

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear what is the problem.

Comment: The image can give more than a thousand characters :( (I added a picture)

Comment: Hm, you probably would get more info by filing a bug report to Chrome devs: http://crbug.com

Answer (score 1):

During the next update, this will be solved. If it doesn't, please submit a bug in http://crbug.com/new